# Why is my Node.js app redirecting me to the failureRedirect route no matter what?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, backend, passport.js

I am making a simple login page using Node.js for back-end stuff and passport for authentication. To me all my code looks good and it looks like it should work. I even put it into chatGPT and it couldn't find any problems, either. No matter the input for the login page, even if it is correct, I get redirected to the failureRedirect page. I know the passwords and emails are correct, even though they are hashed and salted, because I make them extremely simple 3 character passwords for testing purposes. I even seen the hashed password in my DB.

My approach to the problem is taking the submitted input from the user and salting it then hashing it, and storing it to the DB. Then I used the local passport strategy to handle the authentication process by comparing the form input to the user input and if it matches the user will be redirected to a certain page and if not they will be redirected to another page, just for testing purposes. I will include relevant code below to give you a better idea of how I approached this problem.

```
//my User model, exported correctly
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    posts: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post"}
})
```

```
// password hashing code & user creation
asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        // Hash the password
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);

        // Check if user with the provided email already exists
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).exec();

        if (existingUser) {
            return res.status(400).send('Email already exists. Please use a different one.');
        }

        // Create new user
        const user = new User({
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword // Use the hashed password
        });

        await user.save();

        // Redirect after successful registration
        res.redirect("/");
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

```
// snippet of my authentication 
function configurePassport(passport) {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy( async (email, password, done) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: email })
        if (!user) {
          //usernames do not match!
          return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect username" })
        };
        const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
        if (!match) {
            // passwords do not match!
            return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" })
          }
        return done(null, user);
      } catch(err) {
        return done(err);
      };
    }));
}
```

```
  h1= title
  if user 
    h1 Welcome back #{user.firstName}
  else  
    form(action="/", method="post")  
      input(type="email", name="email", placeholder="email")
      input(type="password", name="password", placeholder="password")
      button(type="submit") Log In
    a(href="/register") Register Now
```

```
passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/register"
});
```

So I have included my code for my Schema initialization, user creation and password hashing, the user authentication, and even my login form using pug with the passport.authenticate code. I have tried almost everything and I am not sure where I am going wrong. This is such a simple app that I feel like it has to be something simple. Also the configurePassword function is imported and called in my main app as `configurePassword(passport)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be that the LocalStrategy strategy expects the consistent inputs of username and password every time. I used the input names of email and password instead which is what the problem was. To fix this problem you simply implement naming options at the beginning of the strategy. It would look like this.

```
function configurePassprt(passport) {
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email', //changes the expected form input from username to email
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  async (email, password, done) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ email: email }); // Query database using 'email' field instead of username field
      if (!user) {
        // User with the provided email does not exist
        return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect email" });
      }
      const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      if (!match) {
        // Passwords do not match
        return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" });
      }
      // Authentication successful
      return done(null, user);
    } catch (err) {
      // Error occurred during authentication process
      return done(err);
    }
  }));
}
```